# How align three forms vertically in Elm?

Tags: elm

1) I don't really get for what purpose `Element` and `Form` are different classes. Probably, it causes the following problem.

2)
My `main` function maps all signals to a `assemble` function, which assembles view on each update

```
assemble: Float -> Float -> Element
assemble screen_w screen_h =
    [
        background screen_w screen_h,
        header screen_w screen_h,
        info screen_w screen_h
    ] 
        |> collage (round screen_w)  (round screen_h) 

main: Signal Element
main = 
    assemble
        <~ (toFloat <~ Window.width)
        ~ (toFloat <~ Window.height)
```

This architecture requires `header` to return `Form`

3)
`header` uses one form for text and two other forms to decorate it.

I need to position them one above other and merge into one form.

```
stripe: Float -> Element
stripe w = 
    rect w 10
        |> filled black
        |> show
header: Float -> Float -> Form
header screen_w screen_h =
    [
        stripe screen_w,
        fromString "My awesome header"
            |> height 64
            |> text
            |> show
        ,
        stripe screen_w
    ]
        |> flow down
        |> toForm
        |> move (0, screen_h/2 - header_size/2 - header_shift)
```

4) The code above displays

```
<internal structure> 
<internal structure>
<internal structure>
```

in place of header and stripes.

It seems that `show` is unable to inverse `toForm`

because the following

```
main = 
  show 42
    |> toForm
    |> show
```

also displays

```
<internal structure>
```

Can I align three forms one above other, using Elm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Difference between `Form`s and `Element`s

`Form`s are free-form graphics that can be displayed in a collage. `Element`s are rectangular things with a known width and height.

## Purpose of `Graphics.Element.show`

The `show` function is more of a debugging tool than a function for turning `Form`s into `Element`s. All data you define yourself can probably be displayed by `show`, but some internal data from libraries are not displayable, which is why you get the `<internal structure>` output. To turn `Form`s into `Element`s, use the `Graphics.Collage.collage` function.

## Alignment of `Form`s

Alignment and distribution of forms in an `Element`-like way is not well supported in the core libraries. You can try the 3rd party library [align-distribute](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mgold/Elm-Align-Distribute/1.0.1) for it, which should make it easier. Another more powerful 3rd party library is [diagrams](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/vilterp/elm-diagrams/5.1.0), but I'm not sure it's as easy to use nor whether you need more power than the other lib I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty new to Elm myself, but I think the way to go is to keep each part of the header as a form (don't pipe to show), and move each one individually.  Then header could return a list of Forms, and that would be concatenated with the list in assemble.

So a working header function might look this:

```
import Graphics.Collage exposing (..)
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Text exposing (..)
import Color exposing (..)

main = 
  collage 500 500 (header 500 500)

stripe: Float -> Form
stripe w = 
  rect w 10
    |> filled black


header: Float -> Float -> List Form
header screen_w screen_h =
[
    stripe screen_w
        |> move (0, 245) --calculate based on screen coords
    ,
    fromString "My awesome header"
        |> Text.height 64
        |> text
        |> move (50, 220) --calculate based on screen coords
    ,
    stripe screen_w
        |> move (0, 180) --calculate based on screen coords
]
```

So, in this case the assemble function would look like:

```
assemble: Float -> Float -> Element
assemble screen_w screen_h =
    [background screen_w screen_h] ++
     header screen_w screen_h ++
    [info screen_w screen_h] 
        |> collage (round screen_w)  (round screen_h)
```

Comment: The problem is that it requires calibrating parameters of move each time instead of getting size of the text